# Mongoose increment subdocument array value within another subdocument array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this

```
_id:'111'
products:[
   {
    _id:'pqr'
    nums:[
      {_id:'aaa',
      quantity:50
      },
      {_id:'bbb',
       quantity:50
      }
    ]
   }
]
```

The document above can be summarized like this below for easy understanding.

```
   _id
   products: [
      nums: [
        {}, //quantity is in this object
        {}
      ]
   ]
```

**I need to increment the value of quantity in nums subdocument** which is in products subdocument based on its _id.

This is what I have tried so far but it doesn't work as I don't know how to catch the _id inside nums object so as to update the specific object in that sub-subdocument array.

```
Shop.findOneAndUpdate(
       { "_id": '111', "products._id": 'pqr'  },
          {
            "$inc": {
               "products.$[].nums.quantity": 1
            }
    }
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [arrayfilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#specify-arrayfilters-for-array-update-operations) in update operation :

```
db.getCollection("collectionName").findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "111" }, // Querying against `_id`, need to convert string to `ObjectId()` or instead use `.findByIdAndUpdate()`
  { $inc: { "products.$[p].nums.$[n].quantity": 1 } },
  {
    arrayFilters: [{ "p._id": "pqr" }, { "n._id": "aaa" }] // Inputs here
  }
  // Use { new : true } Option in mongoose to return updated document
);
```

**Input doc :**

```
{
    "_id" : "111",
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "pqr",
            "nums" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "aaa",
                    "quantity" : 50
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "bbb",
                    "quantity" : 50
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "abc",
            "nums" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "aaa1",
                    "quantity" : 501
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "bbb1",
                    "quantity" : 501
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output doc :**

```
{
    "_id" : "111",
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "pqr",
            "nums" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "aaa",
                    "quantity" : 51 // This got incremented
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "bbb",
                    "quantity" : 50
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "abc",
            "nums" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "aaa1",
                    "quantity" : 501
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "bbb1",
                    "quantity" : 501
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Ref :** [mongoose's .findByIdAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)